# Issue with Theano scan function - TypeError: Cannot convert Type TensorType(float64, 3D)

Tags: python, theano

I am having some trouble with the Theano scan function and the following code:

```
def lstm_layer(tparams, options, trng, prefix='lstm'):

def _slice(_x, n, dim):
    if _x.ndim == 3:
        return _x[:, :, n * dim:(n + 1) * dim]
    return _x[:, n * dim:(n + 1) * dim]

def _step(sample_, h_, c_):
    theano.printing.debugprint(sample_,print_type=True)
    emb = tparams['Wemb'][sample_]
    x_ = tensor.dot(emb[None,:], tparams[_p(prefix, 'W')]) + tparams[_p(prefix, 'b')]
    preact = tensor.dot(h_, tparams[_p(prefix, 'U')])
    preact += x_

    i = tensor.nnet.sigmoid(_slice(preact, 0, options['dim_proj']))
    f = tensor.nnet.sigmoid(_slice(preact, 1, options['dim_proj']))
    o = tensor.nnet.sigmoid(_slice(preact, 2, options['dim_proj']))
    c = tensor.tanh(_slice(preact, 3, options['dim_proj']))

    c = f * c_ + i * c
    h = o * tensor.tanh(c)

    pred = tensor.nnet.softmax(tensor.dot(h, tparams['U']) + tparams['b'])
    rand = trng.multinomial(n=1, pvals=pred)
    sample = tensor.argmax(rand[0], axis=0)
    return sample, h, c

start = tensor.scalar('start', dtype='int64')
dim_proj = options['dim_proj']
nsteps = options['seq_length']
rval, updates = theano.scan(_step,
                            outputs_info=[start,
                                          tensor.alloc(numpy_floatX(0.),
                                                       1,
                                                       dim_proj),
                                          tensor.alloc(numpy_floatX(0.),
                                                       1,
                                                       dim_proj)],
                            name=_p(prefix, '_layers'),
                            n_steps=2)
return rval[0], start
```

As you can see, the variable start is an integer that get a new value after each call of step_ and I want to get the sequences of its values after an arbitrary number of steps n_steps. If I run the code with n_steps = 1, everything works. However, for n_steps > 1, I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot convert Type TensorType(float64, 3D) (of Variable IncSubtensor{Set;:int64:}.0) into Type TensorType(float64, (False, True, False)). You can try to manually convert IncSubtensor{Set;:int64:}.0 into a TensorType(float64, (False, True, False)).

I don't get where it comes from as none of my variable is a 3D tensor (I have checked with theano.printing.debugprinting and h and c are rows as expected and sample a scalar).

Do you have any clue?

Thanks

Comment: You clearly provide for `_x` to be 3D given the code inside the `_slice` function. Can you provide some minimal executable code that illustrates the problem because it can be difficult to help with these kinds of errors by just reading code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have found the solution to my problem. I changed this

```
def _slice(_x, n, dim):
if _x.ndim == 3:
    return _x[:, :, n * dim:(n + 1) * dim]
return _x[:, n * dim:(n + 1) * dim]
```

by this

```
    def _slice(_x, n, dim):
    if _x.ndim == 3:
        return _x[:, :, n * dim:(n + 1) * dim]
    if _x.ndim == 2:
        return _x[:, n * dim:(n + 1) * dim]
    return _x[n * dim:(n + 1) * dim]
```

and this

```
x_ = tensor.dot(emb[None,:], tparams[_p(prefix, 'W')]) + tparams[_p(prefix, 'b')]
```

by this

```
    x_ = tensor.dot(emb, tparams[_p(prefix, 'W')]) + tparams[_p(prefix, 'b')]
```

This makes `x_, h_ and c_` theano vector instead of rows as previously and removes the error (though I am not exactly sure why).

Of course I've also update the call to `scan`

```
    rval, updates = theano.scan(_step,
                            outputs_info=[start, tensor.alloc(numpy_floatX(0.),
                                                       dim_proj),
                                          tensor.alloc(numpy_floatX(0.),
                                                       dim_proj)],
                            name=_p(prefix, '_layers'),
                            n_steps=2)
```